# set_timezone error for scottwater/detect_timezone_rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, datetime, timezone

I gem installed https://github.com/scottwater/detect_timezone_rails I want my web app to detect users timezone automatically. Well, I keep getting this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'set_timezone'
```

has anyone experienced this error and how did you solve it? Thanks for your help

in application.js i have the following below

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require detect_timezone
//= require jquery.detect_timezone
//= require jquery-fileupload/basic
//= require jquery-fileupload/vendor/tmpl
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

in my user.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#user_time_zone').set_timezone(); 
})
```

Comment: Can you show some code of how you are using it?

Comment: Thanks for your willingness to help. I have shown how i have used it above